# Calculating frequency in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join, frequency

I am creating a library database and have four tables as follows;

I have been researching ways to work out the frequency in MySQL but after such as long time and misunderstanding I've decided to try get an example of how to work out the frequency on tables that I'll understand. Below are the four tables I am currently using.

**I am looking to workout the loan frequency of every book that has been loaned 2 or more times.** By doing this I am able to see how working out frequency would work when selecting specific values instead of all values.

From looking at my tables I would have to select the 'code' from the loan table, select all values that occur twice or more and then workout the frequency of the occurrence.

From my research I would decide to use an INNER JOIN to connect the tables, COUNT to count the number of values, GROUP BY to group the values and HAVING as WHERE may not be used. I am having trouble writing the query and continuously stumble upon errors. Could anyone use the example above to explain how they worked out the frequency of each book loaned two times or more? Thanks in advance

Table 1 - book

`isbn                 title             author 
111-2-33-444444-5     Pro JavaFX     Dave Smith 
222-3-44-555555-6    Oracle Systems  Kate Roberts 
333-4-55-666666-7    Expert jQuery   Mike Smith`

Table 2 - copy

`code          isbn          duration 
1011     111-2-33-444444-5      21 
1012     111-2-33-444444-5      14 
1013     111-2-33-444444-5      7 
2011     222-3-44-555555-6      21 
3011     333-4-55-666666-7      7 
3012     333-4-55-666666-7      14`

Table 3 - student

`no    name    school    embargo 
2001   Mike      CMP       No 
2002   Andy      CMP       Yes 
2003   Sarah     ENG       No 
2004   Karen     ENG       Yes 
2005   Lucy      BUE       No`

Table 4 - loan

`code    no       taken        due         return 
1011    2002    2015.01.10   2015.01.31   2015.01.31 
1011    2002    2015.02.05   2015.02.26   2015.02.23 
1011    2003    2015.05.10   2015.05.31
1013    2003    2014.03.02   2014.03.16   2014.03.10 
1013    2002    2014.08.02   2014.08.16   2014.08.16 
2011    2004    2013.02.01   2013.02.22   2013.02.20 
3011    2002    2015.07.03   2015.07.10
3011    2005    2014.10.10   2014.10.17   2014.10.20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the type of frequency, but this query calculates the number of loans per week for each book that was loaned more than once in 2014:

```
select  b.isbn
,       b.title
,       count(*) / 52 -- loans/week
from    loan l
join    copy c
on      c.code = l.code
join    book b
on      b.isbn = c.isbn
where   '2014-01-01' <= taken and taken < '2015-01-01'
group by
        b.isbn
,       b.title
having  count(*) > 1 -- loaned more than once
```